# Agrupamiento por filas en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo una duda con respecto a el siguiente código:

```
Select PRESSFORMID,PRESSRUNID,COLOR
From  [PLANNER].[dbo].[PRSUNITS]
WHERE ISSUEID = '37921' AND PRESSFORMID=PRESSFORMID AND PRESSRUNID='1'
GROUP BY PRESSFORMID,PRESSRUNID,COLOR
```

El cual me arroja la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera me ayudaran a hacer un agrupamiento el cual me diera un resultado como este con los mismos valores de la tabla mostrada anteriormente agrupando `PRESSFORMID` y `COLOR` de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No especificas qué gestor usas, mysql? sql server? postgres?

Comment: Es sql managment studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puedes intentar con esto.

Desconozco la estructura de tu tabla pero la cree segun lo que observo tu podrias adaptarlo de ser diferente.

```
SELECT FRO.PRESSFORMID,FRO.PRESSRUNID,
STUFF((SELECT ','+COLOR FROM [PRSUNITS] Stuf WHERE ISSUEID = '37921' AND PRESSRUNID='1' AND Stuf.PRESSFORMID=FRO.PRESSFORMID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as Resultado
FROM
[PRSUNITS] FRO
 WHERE ISSUEID = '37921' AND PRESSRUNID='1' GROUP BY PRESSFORMID,PRESSRUNID
```

Aqui puedes ver el funcionamiento

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/564df/1

Saludos

Comment: Exacto amigo, ese es el resultado que quería lograr.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes utilizar STRING_AGG() algo parecido a esto:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(color, ',')
```

Te adjunto un link donde lo explican bastante bien y con ejemplos.
https://database.guide/the-sql-server-equivalent-to-group_concat/
Espero que te sirva!

Comment: No lo reconoce pero gracias

Comment: Es sql managment studio 2008 perdon

Comment: edito la respuesta

Comment: Me parece que `STRING_AGG()` funciona para sql server 2017 y superior...

Comment: Tengo entendido que si group_concat no tira, la que procede esta.

Comment: Para sql server 2008 tienes la respuesta de [este tema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077155/group-concatmysql-in-sql-server-2008) en el sitio en inglés